# How can I insert a value into a string in a position matched by another string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string variable called selectText that contains the following text:

```
<option value="0101" title="xxxx">A</option><option value="0102" title="xxx">B</option> .....
```

I have a string variable called selectedVal that contains a value that could be either "0101" or "0102" etc

Is there a way using javascript that I can modify selectText to have the words selected="selected" added if I supply selectedVal. So for example if the value of selectedVal was "0102" then I would return the selectText with selected="selected" added to it.

```
<option value="0101" title="xxxx">A</option><option value="0102" selected="selected" title="xxx">B</option>
```

Comment: Are you trying to update/edit a string, or an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').val(selectedVal)
```

or:

```
$('select option[value='+selectedVal+']').prop('selected', true)
```

Or you can set the value of the `select` element by using `val()` method after appending the options:

```
var selectText = '<option value="0101" title="xxxx">A</option><option value="0102" title="xxx">B</option';
var selectVal ='0102';

$('select').append(selectText).val(selectVal)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DrEcq/)

Answer (score 1):

If we were to take what your saying literally in that you have 2 string variables *selectText* and *selectVal* then you just need to use a string `replace` against your *selectText* variable. Like this:

```
var selectText = '<option value="0101" title="xxxx">A</option><option value="0102" title="xxx">B</option>';
var selectedVal = '0102';

var pattern = 'value="' + selectedVal + '"';
selectText = selectText.replace(pattern, pattern + ' selected="selected"');
```

This results in the string variable *selectText* having the following value:

```
<option value="0101" title="xxxx">A</option><option value="0102" selected="selected" title="xxx">B</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selectText = selectText.replace ('"' + selectedValue + '"', 
    '"' + selectedValue + '" selected="selected"');
```

Will search `selectedText` for `selectedValue` enclosed in double quotes and replace that with itself plus the string `'selected="selected"'`. I think that is what you asked for.

Anticipating your next question, use the following to restore the original:

```
selectText = selectText.replace (' selected="selected"', '');
```